# Flow to Call VF Page

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

Does anyone know if it's possible to use a flow to call a VF page that will then create an Account?  I want the flow to have a radion button with 2 choices, each of which will direct the user to a different page to enter the data for the record.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a visualforce page from flow.  You can embed a flow into a visualforce page.

You can also set the flow finish location.. Think for this example you could pass to the visualforce accountCreate page the required/selected fields as querystring parameters.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_adding.htm